# Should [raytracing] be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

The raytracing tag has... 0 watchers and 18 questions. Half of the questions don't have an accepted answer, and of those which do have an answer, the tag doesn't seem to add to or help filter the question:

- [Adaptative ray bounces in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1577/adaptative-ray-bounces-in-cycles) is a good question but the cycles tag seems to cover the raytracing aspect of the question.
- Again, [cycles] seems to cover [Why can't cycles cast one ray per image pixel, instead of rendering progressively to infinity?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/why-cant-cycles-cast-one-ray-per-image-pixel-instead-of-rendering-progressivel) perfectly fine. While the argument that cycles is a very broad tag and raytracing narrows it, the rendering tag does just fine. It makes a lot of sense that if a post is tagged cycles and rendering, it's about raytracing. This makes [raytracing] superfluous in my mind.
- [What is branched path tracing and how is it useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful) is a fantastic question but the cycles and rendering tags make the ray tracing tag unnecessary.
- I think the rendering tag could substitute for raytracing here: [Cycles light ray exiting the back of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/cycles-light-ray-exiting-the-back-of-an-object)
- Raytracing tag seems completely unnecessary for [Boolean on cycles rays, not on mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39962/boolean-on-cycles-rays-not-on-mesh)
- [Associating extra information to a ray in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58879/associating-extra-information-to-a-ray-in-cycles) is probably the one question that does benefit from the tag.

The rest of the 9 answered questions are very similar.

To summarize, half of these questions never get answered and the ones that do just don't benefit from the tag. Raytracing seems to be a simple filler tag on bad questions and a useless afterthought on good questions. With those underwhelming credentials, it seems that it should be removed... Is removal a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. It has been deleted and synonymized with [rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering). For any one who chances on this you're probably better off asking highly technical questions on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/.